# How to add placeholder text to yii inputfield?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

iam using clevertech an extension for YII, dose anybody know how i can add my own custom placeholder text inside the input.
Below is an example of the input filed:

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldGroup(
            $model,
            'textField',
            array(
                'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                ),
                'hint' => 'In addition to freeform text, any HTML5 text-based input appears like so.'
            )
        ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `placeholder` to you html attributes, as follows:

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldGroup(
    $model,
    'textField',
    array(
        'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
            'class' => 'col-sm-5',
        ),
        'hint' => 'In addition to freeform text, any HTML5 text-based input appears like so.',
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Placeholder content',
            ),
        ),
    )
); ?>
```

See http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/forms/view/activeform.html

Comment: it dose not work for me, it takes the default parm that is in the model under Labels

Comment: I updated my example according to the docs, can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldGroup(
        $model,
        'textField',
        array(
            'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                'class' => 'col-sm-5',
            ),
            'widgetOptions'=>array(
                'htmlOptions'=>array('placeholder' => 'Placeholder content')
        )
            'hint' => 'In addition to freeform text, any HTML5 text-based input appears like so.'
        )
    ); ?>
```